# Prime 3-Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I'm trying to understand what the prime 3-manifolds are. Milnor's Prime Decomposition Theorem states that any compact, orientable 3-manifold is a connected sum of a unique finite collection of prime 3-manifolds.

I've read that these prime manifolds will be one of the following:

1. $S^3$ or any quotient of $S^3$
2. $S^2 \times S^1$
3. Some $K(\pi, 1)$ manifold

I'm wondering where this statement comes from. Why these are the only prime 3-manifolds. My thoughts are it could be something to do with $\pi_2$, because Milnor's paper states a 3 manifold is prime $\iff$ $S^2 \times S^1$ or irreducible. The latter condition $\implies$ $\pi_2 =0$.

Thus the prime 3 manifolds are $S^2 \times S^1$ and those with trivial second homotopy group. It is here where I become stuck since I have not formally studied second homotopy groups before.

My question is how do we conclude that the the only 3 options are those stated above?

Comment: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/3-manifolds#Prime_decomposition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the details, which use a lot of additional tools. You can find all these arguments (except for the application of Perelman's theorem) in older 3-manifolds textbooks such as Hempel's "3-manifolds".

Let $M$ be a closed, orientable 3-manifold.

First, the [sphere theorem of Papakyriakopolous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_theorem_(3-manifolds)) says that if $\pi_2(M)$ is nontrivial then there exists an embedding $S^2 \approx S \subset M$ which represents a nontrivial element of $\pi_2(M)$. Nontriviality implies that $S$ does not bound a 3-ball. It follows that if $S$ is separating (or indeed if any other separating sphere exists in $M$ that does not bound a 3-ball), then $M$ is not prime. Finally, if every separating sphere in $M$ bounds a 3-ball, and if $S$ is nonseparating, then a pretty easy separate argument shows $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^1$. Therefore, the conclusion that you desire is true in the case that $\pi_2(M)$ is nontrivial.

So now let's assume that $\pi_2(M)$ is trivial.

Consider the universal covering space $\widetilde M$.

If $\pi_1(M)$ is finite then $\widetilde M$ is a closed, simply connected 3-manifold. Before the work of Perelman, the best conclusion one could make here was that $\widetilde M$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^3$. But nowadays, by applying [Perelman's Theorem, which says that the Poincare conjecture is true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture), it follows that $\widetilde M$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$, and therefore $M$ is a quotient of $S^3$. (A broader statement of Perelman's theorem says that Thurston's whole [geometrization conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture) is true, and therefore $M$ is a [spherical space form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_space_form_conjecture), meaning that $M$ is a quotient of $S^3$ with a deck transformation group consising of isometries of $S^3$).

If $\pi_1(M)$ is infinite, then $\widetilde M$ is noncompact. Applying the [long exact homotopy sequence of a fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Long_exact_sequence_of_homotopy_groups) to the universal covering map $\widetilde M \to M$, it follows that $\pi_2(\widetilde M)$ is homeomorphic to $\pi_2(M)$ and hence is trivial. Since $\pi_1(\widetilde M)$ and $\pi_2(\widetilde M)$ are both trivial, it follows from the [Hurewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem) that $\pi_3(\widetilde M)$ and $H_3(\widetilde M)$ are isomorphic. But noncompactness of $\widetilde M$ implies that $H_3(\widetilde M)$ is trivial; this is one of the side-results accompanying the [Poincare duality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality). Using that $M$ has a 3-dimensional triangulation, and hence so does $\widetilde M$, it follows that all of the higher homology groups $H_n(\widetilde M)$ are also trivial. Again, by applying Hurewicz inductively, it follows that all of the higher homotopy groups $\pi_n(\widetilde M)$ are trivial. Therefore, $\widetilde M$ is contractible and $M$ is a $K(\pi,1)$ space.

Comment: Fantastic answer - thank you. This is the first time I've seen this argument from start to finish which is surprising given that Milnor's prime decomposition theorem must beg exactly the question that I have posed. I'm wondering if you've pieced all of this together yourself, or if this is a well known argument in determining the prime 3-manifolds? Moreover, how is this connected to Thurston's 8 geometries? I presume there is a major difference in his definition of "model geometry" vs that of being prime.

Comment: As said, I believe it's all there in Hempel's book and other 3-manifold books of the time --- Rolfen's "Knots and Links" is another one to check --- except for the added touches of Perelman's Theorem. And even before Perelman, many writers on this topic would craft their theorems to say something like: "and furthermore if the Poincaré conjecture is true then [stronger conclusions hold]". You'll see mention of "fake 3-spheres" or "fake 3-balls" in the conclusions of older references, refering to the possibility of counterexamples to the Poincare conjecture.

Comment: As for the connection to the 8 geometries, that's another question! But here's a preview: besides the prime decomposition, you must also take into account the JSJ decomposition (the torus decomposition) in order to incorporate the 8 geometries.

Comment: @JMill I'm sure Lee Mosher will correct me if I'm wrong, but to me the connection with Thurston geometries is the following: 6 of the geometries correspond to the $ K(\pi,1) $ case since a 3-manifold with geometric structure will admit $ E^3 $, Nil, Solv, $ \tilde{SL_2} $, $ H^2 \times E^1 $, or $ H^3 $ geometry if and only if it is aspherical (which is the same thing as being a  $ K(\pi,1) $). The other two geometries are $ S^3 $ and $ S^2 \times E^1 $.  Manifolds with $ S^3 $ geometry are of course all quotients of $ S^3 $ and moreover are all prime and orientable.

Comment: There are only four compact manifolds with $ S^2 \times E^1 $ geometry. Of these four, only $ S^2 \times S^1 $ is prime and orientable. For the others, $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 $ is orientable but not prime while both $ \mathbb{R}P^2 \times S^1 $ and the mapping torus of the antipodal map of  $ S^2 $ are prime but not orientable.